# Exposed view in field widget submits node form when filtering

Tags: forms, ajax, views

I have defined my own field widget for node_reference fields. This contains a simple view that lets you select a node to reference. However, if i try to use exposed filters as a part of this widget it will try to submit the whole node form every time i press "Apply". Thus i can't use the exposed filters in views. How can i get around this?

I have ajax activated for the view and have tried different types of displays.

EDIT:
Just want to add that i am using Drupal 7 and the latest version of views!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly whether you're using a form here, but if so, you could give this little module a try, that resolved a [similar issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31198/exposed-filter-of-a-view-embedded-in-a-panel-overriding-a-node-form-triggers-nod) of mine.

http://github.com/Itangalo/Node-creation-block--Drupal-7-

creates blocks for node-forms. If you seperate view from the block (e.g. with Panles) this approach could possibly help you too...